# codeigniter HMVC issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, hmvc-codeigniter

I installed the codeigniter HMVC plugin and it's working fine for me but when I try to load any plugin I get the error

> An Error Was Encountered
>   Unable to locate the file: captcha_pi.php

Even if this file exists. I added one more plugin but it's the same. Do plugins work with HMVC?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that captcha is not a plugin, it's a helper (the reference guide example loads it as a plugin).

So, all you need to do is:

```
$this->load->helper('captcha');
```

instead of:

```
$this->load->plugin('captcha');
```

Answer (score 1):

Plugins are a dying breed anyway. What version of CodeIgniter are you using, and what version of HMVC? The most recent is designed to work with CI 2.0 with compatibility for 1.7.x, but it could well be that it's broken. You should [upgrade to CodeIgniter 2.0](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/05/upgrading-to-codeigniter-2.0) anyway.